# Regex getting a specific part of a string only

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to get for example only this:

```
-68.06993865966797
```

from a output of this type:

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "elevation" : -68.06993865966797,
         "location" : {
            "lat" : 27.85061,
            "lng" : -95.58962
         },
         "resolution" : 152.7032318115234
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

How is it possible to only get the string after

> "elevation" :

and end with a comma, but get the string inbetween the colon after elevation until the comma that ends the line

Comment: You should use a `JSON` parser...

Comment: With regex it should be easy but what are you exactly trying to do ? Because regex for this solution might not come in handy when dealing with parsing other JSON.

Comment: just trying to get that part of the output

Comment: "Some people, when confronted with a problem, think
'I know, I'll use regular expressions.'  Now they have two problems." TLDR: This is JSON so use a JSON parser.

Comment: @worpet: You know how this continues, right?  "Now they have two problems. What to do with my spare time now? How to hide my freetime from my Boss?"

Answer (score 1):

Using regex is not recommended for JSON data. Despite that, I put the two ways (i.e. regex and JSON parser) together as follows:

```
import java.util.regex.*;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException {

    String JSON_DATA = "{\n"+
    " \"results\" : [\n"+
    " {\n"+
    " \"elevation\" : -68.06993865966797,\n"+
    " \"location\" : {\n"+
    " \"lat\" : 27.85061,\n"+
    " \"lng\" : -95.58962\n"+
    " },\n"+
    " \"resolution\" : 152.7032318115234\n"+
    " }\n"+
    " ],\n"+
    " \"status\" : \"OK\"\n"+
    "}\n"+
    "";
    // 1. If using REGEX to find all values of "elevation".
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\"elevation\"\\s+:\\s+(-?[\\d.]+),").matcher(JSON_DATA);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println("elevation: " + m.group(1));
    }

    // 2. If using a JSON parser
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(JSON_DATA);
    JSONArray geodata = obj.getJSONArray("results");
    for (int i = 0; i < geodata.length(); ++i) {
      final JSONObject site = geodata.getJSONObject(i);
      System.out.println("elevation: " + site.getDouble("elevation"));
    }
}
```